# Question about risk of bias tools

Tags: methodology, publication-process, publication

I am currently conducting a systematic narrative review for publication and I need to settle on a risk of bias tool. It is a systematic review on mechanisms of change in psychotherapy and therefore I will be looking at intervention studies. Both observational and RCTs will be included in the review and as such I would like to use one risk of bias tool for all studies, such as the EPHPP (https://www.ephpp.ca/quality-assessment-tool-for-quantitative-studies/), as opposed to one tool for RCTs and one tool for one-armed studies.

However, I do not know whether the EPHPP is a well enough validated tool. Therefore, I don't want it to count against me when I send it for publication.

Does anyone know of any well-validated and well-respected 2-in-1 risk of bias tools, or should I stick with the Cochrane (RoB/Robins-I) and/or JBI tools.

Thank you in advance.